# unit testing mock injection

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, junit, mockito

I am trying to unit test my class, and mock the DAO to provide predictable results. Still, it would appear that my DAO's method is still being called as I receive a hibernate error.

> org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Station TST not found.

This error is a result of my database not containing TST, but shouldnt this not even be called since I mocked the DAO? How do I mock the call so that the database isn't even hit.

Here's how I set up my mock

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:applicationContext.xml" })
public class MyServiceTest{

    @Autowired
    private MyService service;

    private MyDAO dao;

    private LinkedList objs;    


    @Before
    public void init() throws SecurityException, NoSuchFieldException,
            IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {


        // mock the dao for predictable results
        dao = mock(MyDAO.class);

        when(dao.myDBCall(anyString(), any(Date.class))).thenReturn(legs);
        Field f = MyService.class.getDeclaredField("dao");
        f.setAccessible(true);
        f.set(service, dao);


    }

    @Test
    public void testCall() {
        // construct our sample leg data
        legs = new LinkedList();
//fill in my stub data i want to return

        Collections.shuffle(legs);

        List results = service.testingCall("TST", new Date()); // this fails because service is using the dao, but it is making a call to the DB with this garbage 'Test' param rather than just returning 'legs' as stated in my when clause
        assertThat(results, not(nullValue()));


    }

    @Test
    public void testGetGates() {
        // fail("Not yet implemented");
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetStations() {
        // fail("Not yet implemented");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For first, instead of `Field f = MyService.class.getDeclaredField("dao");` check for [PowerMock](https://code.google.com/p/powermock/) (check for `Whitebox`)

Mocking one object will not prevent hibernate to start (because you are loading `applicationContext.xml`, so hibernate will try to connect to DB). Your mock - it is just a POJO at one field of one test instance, not a Spring bean or replacement for class.

If you want to test only dao and service classes (create clear unit test) - remove Spring related annotations from test and do it on your own (create mock, create service, put mock to service, and test it).

If you want test your application with Spring context (create integration test) - create [H2 in-memory database](https://boplicity.nl/confluence/display/Java/Unit+testing+JPA+-+Hibernate+components+with+in-memory+H2+database) for hibernate and just test your service (don't forget to clear it in `@After`).

Third way - split your configuration file into two Spring profiles (for example `dev` and `test`) and implement mock yourself (put mock to `test`, real hibernate and dao to `dev`).

If you dont want use Spring profiles - it is possible to split `applicationContext.xml` into 3 files (for common beans, for real DB beans, for mocks).

And one more sexy way - use [springockito-annotations](https://bitbucket.org/kubek2k/springockito/wiki/springockito-annotations) (but you still need to avoid hibernate be loaded)

Comment: H2 is not an option unfortunately. As for 'doing it on my own', my service has many other beans I need to be AutoInjected, making this approach not practical. There really is no way to mock the dao fully?

Comment: You may. For first, move you hibernate-related xml configuration to some ("dev") Spring profile (google for "spring profiles"). Then create your stub (mock) implementation of dao and put it to the "test" profile. After add @ActiveProfiles("test") annotation on test (you also need to activate "dev" profile on regular application start). If you don't like profiles - split configuration in 3 files (applicationContext.xml, dev.xml, mock.xml)

Comment: and here - https://bitbucket.org/kubek2k/springockito/wiki/springockito-annotations :)

Answer (score 2):

I think that your `Service` is instantiated by spring with your `Dao` defined in your `application-context.xml` and you get your error before you even try to inject your mock in your service.

One thing I like to use to test my services is an `Autowired` constructor and then in my tests I do not instantiate my services by spring but using the constructor and the mock.

```
private MyDao myDao;

@Autowired
public MyService(MyDao myDao){
this.myDao = myDao;
}
```

And then in your test :

```
MyService myService = new Myservice(mockedDao);
```

Comment: the error certainly comes after i inject my mock. i can tell by stepping through debugger

Comment: Does your service contains others dao ?

Comment: no just the one, but it does contain other beans i need AutoInjected

Comment: 75inchpianist, Please check my answer... @ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:applicationContext.xml" }) will lead full Spring context and hibernate to start anyway (and mock can't stop it)

Comment: And does those beans require more dao ? Moreover what does @MichailNikolaev says is right, if you load all the springcontext, you are likely to hit the database. What you can do is to either instantiate your bean by hand (like we suggest) or create another context. If it is too painful because of the number of dependency then you have a problem of isolation of concern of your class service and you may want to split it.